# Formidable Forms - UTM issue

Tags: forms, formidable, utm

Hoping someone can quickly help.
Using Formidable forms. Trying to capture the UTM parameters into Pardot.
When i use "[get param="utm_medium"]" or "[get param="utm_source"]" or "[get param="utm_campaign"]" in a hidden field, when i run a test, these values arent being brought over to Pardot. When i look at the entries in Formidable, the three hidden fields are not capturing the UTMs.
Im trying other things like "[siteurl][server param="HTTP_REFERER"]" however, this only captures the referring URL. Is there something or  a simple way i can add something to the server parameter to pull the SOURCE UTM?????

THanks for any help in advance!!